# Can another app user have subscription from same itunes connect after 1st user's subcription gets expired in ios

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscriptions, itunes-store, auto-renewing

If app user 1 purchases a subscription and later he cancels it after some renewals and now app user 2 want to purchase a subscription from the same itunes account, so is this possible and if, how should we handle this on server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one itunes account can be use as one subscription only but if you said user 1 already cancel subscription then obviously if another user come to register with the same itunes account that user is possible to  purchase a subscription because previously user1 cancel his subscription once his cancel you can use flag on database side that this user in cancel subscription and now whoever is using this account can re subscription or purchase new subscription service

but if user1 decided to purchase another subscription with an existing subscription  of user2 now it impossible since they shared same itune account

Comment: Thanks, For a itunes account for a subscription group, each transaction(purchase/renewal) transactionId changes but originalTransactionId remains same ri8? So how we take a subscription is linked to a user(on renewals) until he cancels?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. And to handle it you have to save the Subscription receipt over the server and every time map the new receipt over the server with other receipts. if it does not exist over the server (for your current user) then it's the in-app purchase from new apple id or it's purchased again.

Comment: How do we every time map the new receipt over the server with other receipts?

Comment: by query. Or you can only save the transaction Id over a server and check if the current transaction-id saved against the same user or not.

Comment: But transaction id changes on renewal

Comment: @Kranthi , yes, but with the same transaction, same apple id cannot be used on two devices.  And I am assuming your concern is "one apple user cannot use your app on multiple devices as another app user by only purchasing the subscription one time. Every app user must have to buy the subscription."